# SQL to replace NULL based on other fetched row

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table `T_REF` which contains the following data.

```
select * from T_REF
order by invent_status nulls first;

DIV  REF       INVENT_STATUS
---- --------- -------------
1    REF001XT  NULL
1    REF001XT  A
```

How to get `INVENT_STATUS` as `A` for the following.

- If there is no 2nd row.
- `INVENT_STATUS` is anything other than `A` for 2nd row.

The SQL must not change the first `NULL` if the second row contains an `A`.

**So basically, I need an SQL that replaces an `A` for the `NULL` if there is no `A` in the result of the `SQL`.**

Comment: can we have sample input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need this:

```
select div, ref, invent_status, 
       case when invent_status is null and 
                 count(case when invent_status = 'A' then 1 end) over () = 0 
            then 'A' 
            else invent_status 
       end as new_status
  from t_ref 
  order by invent_status nulls first;
```

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/QZH33308)</sup>**

Conditional, analytical function `count(case when invent_status = 'A' then 1 end) over ()` checks if there are any `A` in your table. If no and if current status is null then it is replaced by `A`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: this is what i did see image]

sample table:

```
create table NS_11(
div int ,ref  varchar(10),INVENT_STATUS varchar(1));

insert into NS_11(div,ref) values(1,'REF001XT');
insert into NS_11 values(1,'REF002XT','A');
insert into NS_11 values(1,'REF003XT','B');
insert into NS_11 values(1,'REF004XT','C');
insert into NS_11(div,ref) values(1,'REF005XT');
insert into NS_11(div,ref) values(1,'REF006XT');
select * from  NS_11;

select div,ref,nvl(INVENT_STATUS,'A') from(select div,ref,INVENT_STATUS from NS_11 
minus select div,ref,INVENT_STATUS from NS_11  where rownum<=1 )
union all
select div,ref,INVENT_STATUS from NS_11 where rownum<=1;
```

sample output:

```
 1  REF002XT    A
 1  REF003XT    B
 1  REF004XT    C
 1  REF005XT    A
 1  REF006XT    A
 1  REF001XT    (null)
```

this query will work  for your table:

```
select div,ref,INVENT_STATUS from T_REF where rownum<=1 
union
select div,ref,nvl(INVENT_STATUS,'A') from(select div,ref,INVENT_STATUS from T_REF 
minus select div,ref,INVENT_STATUS from T_REF  where rownum<=1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select DIV, REF,
       case
           when (INVENT_STATUS is null) then 'A'
           when INVENT_STATUS = 'A' then null
           when INVENT_STATUS != 'A' then INVENT_STATUS
       else INVENT_STATUS
       end as INVENT_STATUS
from
    t_ref
order by INVENT_STATUS nulls first;
```